# Difference between prototype and prototype._

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

What is the difference between

```
prototype.somefunction()
```

and

```
prototype._anotherfunction()
```

I know this might be trivial, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One has an underscore in the name.  There's no difference as far as the javascript engine itself is concerned.

However, it's a common convention to name "private" methods such that they start with an underscore.

Comment: Its a convention? So that means in javascript terms its actually a function which can be called on the object by anyone?

Comment: @SaranshMohapatra Yes, it's just a sign to maybe think twice before doing so.  (And in a library, an indication that there's a way higher chance of it breaking on an upgrade.)

Answer (score 1):

`_` prefix means that method is supposed to be private, not more than that